# mac10.8 NPAPI plugin not load on opera

Tags: macos, opera, npapi

I write a web plugin on mac10.8 with Xcode4.5,it can work on safari,firefox, but it can't work on opera,the question is opera can't load my plugin,the easy question is it can'n  execute the
function "NP_GetEntryPoints" and "NP_Initialize", and i don't know how to resolve the problems.
somebody can help me,thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to develop NPRuntime Plugin on Opera in Mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407207/how-to-develop-npruntime-plugin-on-opera-in-mac)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wouldn't surprise me if you are building it 64 bit and Opera may not support 64 bit plugins (but both firefox and Safari do).

Make sure you're building it 32 bit and see if it works.

Comment: Opera 12.00 and above is itself 64-bit, and definitely supports 64-bit plugins.